# How to check if SharedPreferences file exists or not

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I am looking an android Shared Preferences and I am wondering is there a way to just check if the preferences file exists.

```
   SharedPreferences  mySharedPreferences ; 
mySharedPreferences=getSharedPreferences(“Name_of_your_preference”,mode);
```

This above code leads me to believe that "Name_of_Your_preferene" is stored as a file or some sort of container that will contain your preferences.

I am wondering is there away to check if this exists or not. When a user loads up an activity I want to save all the settings into this file with some default values(off for all settings). However I only want to do this if they are going to the page for the first time.

Otherwise if I would do something like this every time the page loads up

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor= mySharedPreferences.edit();

/* now store your primitive type values. In this case it is true, 1f and Hello! World  */

editor.putBolean(“myBoolean”,true);

editor.putFloat(“myFloat”,1f);

editor.putString(“myString”,” Hello! World”);
```

I am guessing it would override all settings even ones they set.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The SharedPreferences are saved in a xml file. You can find it in /data/data/your_application_package/shared_prefs/Name_of_your_preference.xml

To check if the SharedPreferences 'Name_of_your_preference' exist :

```
File f = new File(
"/data/data/your_application_package/shared_prefs/Name_of_your_preference.xml");
if (f.exists())
    Log.d("TAG", "SharedPreferences Name_of_your_preference : exist");
else
    Log.d("TAG", "Setup default preferences");
```

Regards.

Comment: So I just browse there through the emulator?

Comment: how do you get to that folder

Comment: f.exists() was crashing my app.  even after adding try catch, exception wasn't caught.. It just crashed.

Comment: new File(
"/data/data/your_application_package/shared_prefs/Name_of_your_preference.xml");

This will always evaluate to true excepts if it throws exception, right?
Because you're creating a new File, not checking if it previously exist.
Note: This is a question with a thought.

Comment: `new File()` will not create a new file. To create the file, it's the `f.createNewFile()`.

Answer (score 20):

You can use the `contains` method on the `SharedPreferences` object to check if one of your preference keys exist in the file. If this returns `false`, you can assume this is the first time and populate the default settings. The documentation for this method is [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html#contains%28java.lang.String%29).

I couldn't find any way to check if a preference file already exists (it will be created automatically the first time you retrieve an editor), but this method should do the trick.

Comment: how about if I use getAll() since it would only get preferences form the "Name_of_your_preference" right? So if the count would be zero I guess it would not be created?

Comment: Should work as well. It's a matter of preference, I suppose, but in the case of ``getAll()`` you would have to instantiate a ``Map`` object just to check its size. The original method just seems like a quicker boolean test.

Comment: I am using monodroid. It has a count function so I think I am alright.

Answer (score 7):

I did not have enough reps to comment natur3's post. Therefore this answer.

@natur3: Very helpful, thankyou. I hade a small problem however... with the file suffix. If i define my filename like this:

```
    private static final String FILENAME = "myPrefs";
```

And then use:

```
    File f = new File("/data/data/" + getPackageName() +  "/shared_prefs/" + FILENAME);
```

f.exists() will return false even if the file exists on the filesystem. This is because Android will add the ".xml" suffix automatically when writing SharedPreferences so i had to make my file reference look like this:

```
    File f = new File("/data/data/" + getPackageName() +  "/shared_prefs/" + FILENAME + ".xml");
```

for it to work. I don't know where u got your "_preferences.xml" suffix from.

I managed to figure this out by browsing the emulator filesystem in Eclipse using Window->Show View->Other... and then select "File Explorer".

Answer (score 4):

Rather than hard-coding the "/data/data/" path you can do this:

```
public boolean preferenceFileExist(String fileName) {
    File f = new File(getApplicationContext().getApplicationInfo().dataDir + "/shared_prefs/"
            + fileName + ".xml");
    return f.exists()
}
```

Comment: Note: `getApplicationInfo().dataDir` returns `/data/user/0` on newer Android versions

Answer (score 1):

I did it this way so its adaptable imo.

```
File f = new File("/data/data/" + getPackageName() +  "/shared_prefs/" + getPackageName()+ "_preferences.xml");

if(f.exists())
{ 
     //do stuff`enter code here`
}
```

I used this in a validation process at the onCreate if the preferences exists or not and depending on the answer enable a button to clear the preferences or not - just verify what the name of your preference file is in DDMS if its not manually named.

Comment: Hi natur3, Shouldnt the file path read: File f = new File("/data/data/" + getPackageName() +  "/shared_prefs/_preferences.xml");    without the second getPackageName()? When I used your code this went to a non existent directory and so wouldnt save.

Answer (score 0):

The most easy way i found ,
we can check if the Shared preference exist by a built in code on android

```
 sharePrefName.contains(String key) // as if (userData.contains("name")){Toast // Your data is already here!}
```

Checks whether the preferences contains a preference. (it's abstract boolean public method)

Simple and easy :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a more accurate solution

```
val file = File(filesDir.parent, "shared_prefs/name_of_preference.xml")
```

or just

```
val file = File(filesDir, "../shared_prefs/name_of_preference.xml")
```

Answer (score 0):

My take on a solution:

```kotlin
/**
 * Returns the shared preferences directory.
 */
val Context.sharedPrefsDir get() = File(filesDir.parentFile, "shared_prefs")

/**
 * Check if the SharedPreferences file exists in the shared preferences directory
 */
fun Context.settingsFileExists(file: String) = File(sharedPrefsDir, "$file.xml").exists()

/**
 * Opens the shared preferences as by getSharedPreferences if it exists,
 * but does NOT create the file if it does not yet exist.
 */
fun Context.getSharedPreferencesOrNull(file: String, mode: Int = Context.MODE_PRIVATE) =
        if(settingsFileExists(file))
            getSharedPreferences(file, mode)
        else
            null
```

This makes me able to say things like

```kotlin
val myPrefs = Context.getSharedPreferencesOrNull("alternativeConfigFile") ?: Context.getSharedPreferences("mainConfigFile")
```

without android creating "alternativeConfigFile.xml" behind the scenes.