# How to properly save using Shared Preferences

Tags: android, android-intent

So I have a basic app. Consisting of 3 activities. A,B & C. A is the main menu in which it has buttons named 'New Game', 'Load Game'. B contains 3 buttons named, 'Easy', 'Hard' and 'Medium'. C contains the actual game. When the user presses 'new game' in A, it send an intent to start B. when the user clicks on easy, medium or hard, it sends an intent along with some information to start C. When the user clicks on 'continue' in A, it creates an intent to start C and passes a boolean value (see `onStart();` below).

I need to save the game state. I am doing this by using sharedPreferences. This an overview of how I structured my saving/loading. This is in C activity:

```
public void saveData(){
    Log.d("saving","In the saveData() method");
    SharedPreferences prefFile = getSharedPreferences("brainData", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor prefEditor = prefFile.edit();
//... my saving occurs here
prefEditor.apply();
}
public void loadData(){
        Log.d("saving","In the loadData() method");
        SharedPreferences prefFile = getSharedPreferences("brainData", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
//reading from prefFile to load the data occurs here
}

public void onStart(){
        super.onStart();
        Log.d("saving", "On start method()");
        Bundle loaded = getIntent().getExtras();

        if(loaded.getBoolean("beingLoaded")){
            Log.d("saving","Data being loaded");
            loadData();
        }else{
            Log.d("saving","Data not being loaded");
            //New game is created here since no data found
        }

    }

public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

        if(questionCounter < 10){
            Log.d("saving","saving via onPause()");
            saveData();
        }
}
```

In the onPause(); it saves if the questionCounter is below 10. questionCounter increments everytime the user gets an answer right. In my game, there is a total of 10 questions hence it makes sense not to save it after 10 questions since the game ends after 10 questions.

Basically, when I test my app, I click on new game, select my difficulty and play till i answered 4 questions, I press back and I am brought to activity A (B and C have noHistory:true in manifest). I then press 'continue' and it doesn't load. I set a small test condition in the continue button which displays a toast if there is not save data found. The toast gets displayed. Why is this when I am clearly saving when onPause gets called. Even my Log.d messages gets displayed so why am I not able to continue?

Comment: when do you call your loadData() method

Comment: I call it in my onStart() method

Comment: try calling it in onResume() of the activity

Comment: Tried that. Doesn't work. The problem is that when I click on continue in activity A, it doesn't read the save file hence it displays that toast message. Im certain the file is being saved when the user exists from C since the Log.d messages are being called appropriately

Comment: your code doesn't actually show how are you saving the prefs. May be there is some problem there

Comment: I just fixed it. It was the way I was checking if there was a save file present in my continue onClick method in activity A. One question, how do I check if a sharedpreference file exists?

Comment: you can't check the existence of the file directly, You can get a value from it, that way you will know

Comment: Check this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6962030/how-to-check-if-sharedpreferences-file-exists-or-not) for implementing a code to see whether the file exists or not